# Writing sbt plugin that exports itself to child projects?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to write a plugin that makes its code available to projects that uses the plugin.

The plugin would be defined as follows:

```
package mypackage

object MyPlugin extends sbt.Plugin {
  ...
}

trait MyInterface {
  ...
}
```

A client code should be able to export and instantiate `mypackage.MyInterface` to make possible for plugin distinguish `MyInterface` instances during parsing Analysis API info.

I should add that I would like to create separate `config` for doing some code testing (existing test are not suited for me) and plugin would be exported only to this config's classpath.

If someone would like to ask if this approach is legitimate I answer that sbt itself uses this method for working with plugins. I've found almost no documentations for writing sbt plugins and was forced to peek inside the sbt code. There I found similar cases and some hints. But the code is too complicated full of macroses and DSL with lack of documentation strings, so I grasp only part of it.

Answer (score 0):

My rather limited knowledge about sbt lets me argue about the merits of your question and what you're going to achieve.

Since a plugin is a part of the build and should (merely) help the project's artifact(s) see the light of production release, it should in no way be the artifact's dependency as you'd have to release the dependency (that's a sbt plugin in its current form) so others would be able to download it, too.

What you'd rather do is to have a plugin that wraps a dependency and when included in a build makes the dependency a dependency of your project. That's acceptable in my opinion.

How much do I differ from your use case? I'd happy to refine the answer after having heard some additional information.

Comment: I've expanded initial question with info that you had required